# Error in the def area for datetime series

Tags: python, datetime

There is 2 error in the def area. This there any answer to the correct code that can amend the error?

I manage to found 1 which is at `num_days.append(txn_dt - start_date)`.

> The error is `UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'subtract' cannot use operands with types dtype('<M8[D]') and dtype('float64')`.

But I do not understand it. Is there a solution to it?

It supposed to give me 2 output of

```
[1450.32, 1455.42, 1443.12, 1528.82, 1473.37]
```

and

```
[0, 12, 2, 12, 5]
```

This is the info of the code.

```
 all_txn_dates = [np.datetime64('2020-01-01'),
                      np.datetime64('2020-01-13'), 
                      np.datetime64('2020-01-15'),
                      np.datetime64('2020-01-27')]



all_txn_amt = [5.10,-12.30,85.70,-55.45]

balance = 1450.32




def cal_daily_bal(last_balance, txn_dates, txn_amts):
    month = np.datetime64(txn_dates[0],'M')
    datelist = pd.date_range(month, month+1)
    start_date = np.datetime64(datelist[0],'D')
    daily_bal = [balance]
    num_days = []
    for i, txn_dt in enumerate (txn_dates):
        num_days.append(txn_dt - start_date)
        start_date = txn_amts[i]
        daily_bal.append(daily_bal[-1] + txn_amts[i])   
    num_days.append(np.datetime64(datelist[-1],'D') - txn_dates[-1])
    return daily_bal , num_days
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the wring `start_date = txn_amts[i]` in the for loop, and you get

```
all_txn_dates = [np.datetime64('2020-01-01'), np.datetime64('2020-01-13'),
                 np.datetime64('2020-01-15'), np.datetime64('2020-01-27')]
all_txn_amt = [5.10, -12.30, 85.70, -55.45]
balance = 1450.32

a, b = cal_daily_bal(balance, all_txn_dates, all_txn_amt)

print(a)  
# [1450.32, 1455.4199999999998, 1443.12, 1528.82, 1473.37]

print(b) 
# [numpy.timedelta64(0,'D'), numpy.timedelta64(12,'D'), numpy.timedelta64(14,'D'), numpy.timedelta64(26,'D'), numpy.timedelta64(5,'D')]
```

To get second list to be `[0.0, 12.0, 14.0, 26.0, 5.0]` change the end of `cal_daily_bal` to

```
return daily_bal, [x / np.timedelta64(1, 'D') for x in num_days]
```